# MS Test Dictate Dialog Click event c#

Tags: c#, automated-tests, mstest

I have a method that looks like:

```
public void CloseInputTab()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel? Any Unsaved changes will be lost", "Confirm Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
    }
```

I'm working on writing two automated test cases.
1) Verify Stuff happens if OK was clicked
2) Verify Stuff didn't happen if Cancel was clicked

Is there a way in the Visual Studio testing tools to Click the appropriate button for each test.

If not I could copy the code out to a Mocked class that is available to me but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Do you use WinForms or WPF to implement UI?

Comment: You *could* use Coded UI, but having your presentation logic be separate from your business logic is the correct approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, it would be great to stick to the [Model-View-Presenter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). ([How to: Unit Test a Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648002.aspx))

If you are using WPF, please consider using [Model-View-ViewModel pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).
They are both provide testability.

**Update**

Here is an example: [(MVP) Model View Presenter - Passive View](http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2010/01/16/%28MVP%29-Model-View-Presenter-Passive-View.aspx) with the message box.

Comment: thanks Yeah I'm familiar with the MVP Pattern and it just seems silly to pull out the Message box to pop in the view and return the result but I guess it is the easiest solution. I was just hoping there was another way